# Extract String value from a TreeMap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

Map 1 is a TreeMap and Map2 is a HashMap

How to extract value `(String3[])` in a String array from a `TreeMap (Map1)` in Java. `TreeMap` is of type `Map1<String1,Map2<String2,String3[]>>`

I have used `TreeMap.getKey().contains(String2)` to get the Key of String 2. But I need to extract the values of the corresponding key i.e. `String2` and store them in a string array.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you post your code snippet, and what you tried so far?

Comment: What do those suffixes (1,2,3) mean? What are your values? Do you want to access all String3[] arrays or just one and if so, which one?

Comment: @choeger : I used suffixes 1,2,3 just to make it clear to you guys on what I wanted to extract. I want to access String3[] of a particular String2. basically for Map2 (which is a value of Map1), String 2 is the key and String3[] is the value which is a String array. I want to extract String3[] for a particular String2 and store it in a String array.

Comment: In that case see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Map<A, Map<B, C>>` and want to access a specific `C`, you will need both an `A` and a B that tell you which `C`. Then you can use `map.get(a).get(c);`

Any map in the Java standard library (regardless of the concrete implementation) offers a `get(key)` method that yields a value for the given key (or `null` in case the key is not mapped).

In your case this means you need two keys: A `String1` and a `String2`. With the former you `get()` a map from which you can `get()` your desired result using the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection entrySet = treeMap.entrySet();

    // Obtain an Iterator for the entries Set
    Iterator it = entrySet.iterator();

    // Iterate through TreeMap entries
    System.out.println("TreeMap entries : ");
    while(it.hasNext())

System.out.println(it.next());
  }
```